# Why do quoted 2-tuples have a different representation than other n-tuples?

Tags: elixir

The [Quote and unquote guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html#quoting) states:

> Besides the tuple defined above, there are five Elixir literals that,
>   when quoted, return themselves (and not a tuple). They are:
>
> ```
> :sum         #=> Atoms
> 1.0          #=> Numbers
> [1, 2]       #=> Lists
> "strings"    #=> Strings
> {key, value} #=> Tuples with two elements
> ```

Playing with iex confirms this:

```
iex(1)> quote do: {}
{:{}, [], []}
iex(2)> quote do: {1}
{:{}, [], [1]}
iex(3)> quote do: {1,2}
{1, 2}
iex(4)> quote do: {1,2,3}
{:{}, [], [1, 2, 3]}
```

Why are only 2-tuples represented by themselves, and not other n-tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [Syntax Reference](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/eda99eb989347bded9ec9ecd8e2d6f2feff56f82/lib/elixir/pages/Syntax%20Reference.md#keywords):

> Remember that, because lists and two-element tuples are quoted literals, by definition keywords are also literals (in fact, **the only reason tuples with two elements are quoted literals is to support keywords as literals**).

I believe one benefit of this is that a macro can extract values from keyword lists easily.